# how set the windows clock using c++

Tags: c++, winapi, time

I'm trying set the windows system clock using C++.
I'm trying with the following code(not working):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    SYSTEMTIME st;
    st.wDay = 1;
    st.wMonth = 5;
    st.wYear = 2011;
    st.wHour = 12;
    st.wMinute = 15;
    bool result = SetLocalTime(&st);
    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone point out my error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SetLocalTime` returns `BOOL` instead of `bool`, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724936(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @WTP well, it returns `BOOL`, and is marked `WINAPI` (`__stdcall`). It doesn't return a `WINAPI` :) Also Mask, you'll need to say _how_ your code is not working, not just that it isn't.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie I've never used Windows API's. I simply read the documentation. Thanks for the information, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

st is incompletely initialized and contains invalid values.   Initialize it fully and the code works.  If you had called GetLastError(), it would have clued you in right away because it was returning 87, which is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.  The day of week, seconds and milliseconds fields undoubtedly contain invalid values.

Comment: thanks! and other note: the type of values is `WORD` not `int` as I have set

Answer (score 6):

Which Windows version? On Vista+, you need admin privileges to set the time. Run your program as administrator and it should work.

Well, as Adam wrote below, admin privileges is not strictly required but let's start to make it work the easy way ;-)

Also, I would ZeroMemory(&st, sizeof(st)) to make sure extra members such as seconds don't contain unacceptable values. Better yet, just initialize all members of the struct.

Comment: Technically you need the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege, which you get by being an Administrator, but that's not the only way to do it.

Comment: Agreed. I was looking up the required priv while you wrote your comment ;-)

Comment: See my edit about st initialization. What does GetLastError() say?

Comment: @Serge: GetLastError() // this says 87

Answer (score 4):

From the SetLocalTime() documentation:

The calling process must have the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege. This privilege is disabled by default. The SetLocalTime function enables the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege before changing the local time and disables the privilege before returning. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges.

A possible solution is turning on UAC in the Linker Options:

Open the project-properties dialog, go to Linker->Manifest and set UAC to "requireAdministrator".

The downside is you then have to run Visual Studio as Administrator to debug your program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did it but still does not work and SetLocalTime returns 0 for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the parameters you don't need to 0.

Replace:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
```

with:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
ZeroMemory(&st, sizeof(st));
```